# Timezone not changing after using date_default_timezone_set

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I'm setting my default time zone for my page using:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
```

I have to set it there, because my server doesn't allow me to alter the php.ini file or .htaccess. The problem is, when I use this:

```
NOW()
```

to send the current time to my database, it still send it as the UTC timezone.

What I'm trying to do is display comments users display from a comment box on the page, and it's showing the time for each of the comments in the wrong timezone now.

Comment: Is NOW() not a database function? Use time() instead if you are using PHP?

Comment: Please specify the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date_default_timezone_set` is a PHP function. It can only affect the behaviour of PHP.

`NOW()` is a database function, and changing your timezone in PHP has no effect on it. `NOW()` returns in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

`time()` is the equivalent PHP function. `time()` returns simply the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch. To get output in the same format as `NOW()`, use `date("Y-m-d H-i-s");`. This automatically uses `time()` underneath to get the current system time.

Read more:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now
- http://php.net/time
- http://php.net/date

Answer (score 0):

From the manual

> date_default_timezone_set — Sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions in a script

Thus, use the date_default_timezone_set function only affects those functions. You should instead use [`time()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) instead.

Comment: would time() still insert the current time the same way into my database when I post the info to it?

Comment: It will give you the UNIX timestamp. If you use the link in my answer, you'll see that time() returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

So it will give you an output as an integer.

Comment: Do you need the format to be the same as NOW()? If you do, use the date() function instead.http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: both ways are giving me an error and not saving the time to the database

Comment: You cannot just type date(), you need to configure the string format, as stated in the manual. RTFM.